# How do I reference an instance variable in lua?

Tags: lua

```
function example()
    help = "no"
end

meme = example()

print(meme.help)
```

This code throws a run-time error.
I don't know what to do.

I'm trying to teach myself lua and I know this can be done in java, but I can't get it working in lua.

Comment: http://puu.sh/djClh/1d4312f5cf.png

Comment: im using the corona sdk

Comment: You're not `return`ing any value from `example()`, see my answer.

Comment: Key concept: There are two ways to create something new in Lua: evaluating a table constructor `{}` creates a new table value; evaluation a function definition `example = function() end` creates a new function value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, but from your question it seems that you want to emulate the object-oriented features of Java.

Keep in mind that Lua has no "instance variables" since it has no classes. Lua object oriented approach is uncommon and, unlike Java, is sort of prototype-based object orientation.

A very basic approach to creating an object with instance variables and methods is the following:

```lua
-- this is the "instance"
myobject = {}
-- this defines a new "instance variable" named `help`
myobject.help = "this is the help text"

-- this defines a getter method for the instance
-- the special name `self` indicates the instance
function myobject:GetHelp()
    return self.help
end

-- this defines a setter method for the instance
function myobject:SetHelp( help_text )
    self.help = help_text
end

print( myobject:GetHelp() )
myobject:SetHelp( "new help text" )
print( myobject:GetHelp() )
```

You can discover more about object orientation in Lua browsing the links in
[Lua WIKI's page about object oriented programming](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH
I didn't even realise

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning in your function.

If the function doesn't return anything `example()` doesn't have a value, thus you're receiving a `nil value` error:

[image]

Using as the code is being *`return`ed*, using `help.meme` will not work. As it is the *only* variable returned you can simply use this in your use case:

The below code will fix this:

```
function example()
    help = "no"
end

example()

print(help)
```

Comment: http://puu.sh/djCCK/5eb36e5abe.png

now it prints nil instead of throwing an error

Comment: @JosephFazekas I modified the code, it will now return correctly.

Comment: Thanks this helps, but I dont only want the code to print the value.
I want to be able to change it as well. @cybermonkey

Comment: @JosephFazekas You're probably looking for a table or global value. Simply change `meme = example()` with `meme = "[whatever text you want here]`".

Comment: @JosephFazekas Please review my code modification, that will work. I'll also be grateful if you could upvote and mark my accept my answer (click the tick by the question).

Comment: I wish I could send the whole code but I think that would be too messy, basically I'm creating multiple objects in a table called units. So then I want edit a specific value for just one of them.

for example I was trying this
units[1].value = 3

but this gives me an error

Comment: Sorry, I did the check thing now, but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: @JosephFazekas Unless `units` has a variable called `value`, your code is incorrect. You want `units[1] = 3`.

Comment: http://puu.sh/djECn/1c60d5cebc.png
this is basically what im trying to do, but i get this error
http://puu.sh/djEEE/6fa12a7657.png

Comment: Did you mean to assign the ***same variable*** 10 times? As mentioned above ***You cannot use `units[1].value`, you must use `units[1]` only.***

Comment: i thought this created multiple instances of the item() object like it does in java

Comment: @JosephFazekas Lua and Java are completely different languages. In order to create multiple instances use `units[i] = item()` inside your loop.

Comment: thats what i meant, but even so it still gives the error